# Wordpress form data

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have to work on already created website. My task is to find out that which emails are configured to receive contact form data which end user will enter. I can edit the contact form in Elementor but unable to see the email where this data will be sent out?

My second question is can we edit the community plugins code, if so what will be consequences when the plugin will be updated?

Comment: https://wpastra.com/contact-forms-with-elementor/ - look at step 3. And never directly edit a plugin's code - unless you plan on never updating it. You will lose all changes you made.

Comment: I think step 3 is for creating new forms. I have already contact form, in fact many forms but i don't know which email recipient is configured through Elementor which receives these forms data, usually there is some email where these forms data are sent out e.g sales team email